# Can I run virtualbox on my ubuntu server to host a windows10 guest but run it natively?

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualbox

I'm running pc with an i5, 24gb ram, gtx1060 with ubuntu server 18.04.

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to install virtualbox and run an instance of windows 10 but then use windows 10 natively with k/m and monitor plugged directly into the server, instead of through remote desktop?

I basically want to retain 3d acceleration to play the odd game.

Or is playing games via virtual machine not feasible?

Can i install X on ubuntu server?

Comment: Yes you can install X on a [Ubuntu] server, https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/virtualbox lists dependencies for virtualbox, and those could pull in other deps, however many games won't run inside virtualbox as they need to use what virtualbox provides (not real hardware) so it may not run the games you are thinking of.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your answer. I managed to install X and get my nvidia drivers installed. But I've been doing more reading and I wont be able to access my Nvidia graphics through the VM to play games.